# Sigma-finiteness of a point mass measure

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{e}_{a}(x)$ denote point-mass at the point $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\nu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{e}_{a_{n}}$. What are properties of the sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ that render $\nu$ sigma-finite?

I would really appreciate any help you could give me!

Comment: No point occurs infinitely often in the sequence $a_n$.

Comment: Daniel, how do you know that?

Comment: If one point occurs infinitely often, any set containing it has infinite mass, so $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. If every point occurs only finitely many times in the sequence, you have countably many singletons with a finite mass, and one null set with countable countable complement to write $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of sets with finite mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is needed is the sequences countability, provided all of these points have finite measure. Do you mean measure 1 for these point-masses -- I am a little unsure?

Your enumeration of the sequence should be 1-1 or you have to worry about an infinity of measure piling up at a particular point.

Comment: Yeah, 1 if the point a is in a given set, 0 if it is not contained in that set. Is the sequence countable because it is a sequence of discrete points? And WHY is the sequence being countable sufficient?

Comment: To be $\sigma$ finite, you must be able to write a countable measurable partition of the set into subsets of finite measure.  The sequence, along with the one of other set, its complement, is such a partition.  Note that the complement has measure 0.